# putting multiple selections from dropdown into sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the select2 multiple dropdown tags select plugin. On form submit i've got it putting the info into my database.

When just using `$this->input->post('sellingmethods')` it only inputs the last option selected.

I want to put them into my database like option1,option2,option3

so i tried using implode

```
'sellingmethods' => implode(',', $_POST['sellingmethods']),
```

however I keep being thrown the error :

`Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed`

any ideas?

Comment: sellingmethods[] ?

Comment: This is **extremely** risky. If you're going to bypass the placeholder system when making queries you **must** properly escape that for SQL.

Comment: Your `$_POST` entry is probably not defined.

Comment: before you try to implode values, check if any values exists... `if(isset($_POST['sellingmethods']) && is_array($_POST['sellingmethods'])){ }`

Comment: @tadman or at least validate them against predefined values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error trying to use `$_POST['sellingmethods']` as an array, which means that it's not an array. This makes me think you have not named your control correctly. Look at this example and notice the brackets in the name and the use of the multiple attribute.

```
<select name="sellingmethods[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">method 1</option>
  <option value="2">method 2</option>
  ...
</select>
```